# How to force traffic via Laptop VPN by reconfiguring AWS server side?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

A developer wants a VPN-restricted S3 bucket. I have configured the S3 bucket to only accept connections via the VPN.

The VPN however isn't used by default for all connections, so requests are currently denied. Because it's connecting to the S3 bucket without the VPN, even though Viscosity is connected to the VPN.

He doesn't want all developers to have to change their VPN client settings to force access to the S3 bucket via the VPN.

What would be the easiest way to make this possible?

Comment: what kind of vpn did you configure.

Comment: I'm confused. Are you wanting the bucket to be restricted to _only_ be accessible via the VPN, or not? You seem to be upset that it is doing what you wanted.